# How to transform word in dataFrame into plural in scala

Tags: scala

I have a beginner's question, say I have a dataFrame below:

```
wordsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('cat',), ('elephant',), ('rat',), ('rat',), ('cat', )], ['word'])
```

How do I transform all the items to plural by adding 's' at the end?

My code `pluralDF = wordsDF.select(concat(col("word"), lit("s"), col("word")))` gives error:

> name 'col' is not defined

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be very simple:

```
pluralDF = wordsDF.select(concat(wordsDF['word'], lit("s")).alias("plural"))
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer and close this topic.